# Problem with Scale Dependent Rendering after Upgrade to QGIS 2.18.6

Tags: qgis

I upgraded from QGIS 2.8.1 to 2.18.6 and all seems very nice.

One problem I have is with display.  Some, though not all, of my line and point layers won't display unless I zoom in.  All my polygon layers display at all scales.

The affected layers do **not** have Scale Dependent Visibility enabled for the layer.  So I'm not sure why this behavior is occurring.

I'm having to zoom way in to see them -- so much so that it is not practical.

UPDATE: I've narrowed down the problem, but haven't found a solution. It's one of the layers.  When I turn on labeling for that layer, all features in that layer suddenly disappear, and most (but not all) of my other vector layers also disappear.  If I disable display of the offending layer, display of all other layers is restored.  This issue does not occur with 2.8.1, but occurs consistently in 2.18.6.

Comment: Can you try to re-build `Spatial Index` on your affected layers?

Comment: Tried Layer Properties > General > Coordinate reference system > Create spatial index.  Unfortunately had no effect.

Comment: Workaround discovered.  If I create a new project with the same data I do not have this problem.  It appears to be an artifact of opening in 2.18.6 a project created in 2.8.1.

Comment: Did you create the new project from scratch? Or is it a copy created by `Save As` command in 2.18.6? Anyway, that's great!

Comment: Saving As doesn't fix the problem.  Creating a new project from scratch works.  To speed up process, I grouped layers and then saved the group as a layer definition file.  That QLR file can then be added to a new 2.18.6 project without the display problem.  A relatively quick work around for the layers, but any project-specific properties would have to be recreated in the new project.

Comment: The Save As workaround may not be enough.  I've updated the original post to better indicate the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same issue with Girona 3.0.3; even though I change the scale based visibility, it stays unchanged.

The workaround I used was to export the concerned layer and manually apply the same format from the old layer. This worked for me.